# Group identical files after comparing them at the binary level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of files which I need to group into groups of identical files.

Example, I have files as below

```
File1
File2
File3
File4
File5
File6
File7
File8
```

I have used `filecmp.cmp()` and `for` loops to iterate through the list of file and compared all to all, and dumped the results into a dataframe.  Then I have filtered the dataframe to get a subset dataframe containing only pair of files which are identical in Col1 and Col2. For example, see below.  It shows that `File1 == File2`, `File1 == File3`, and so on,

[image]
Now I want to group identical files.  I need to add a column called 'Group' which shows the same group number for identical files.  Rows 0,1,2 and 3 would be Group1 because File1, File2, File3 and File4 are identical (File2 = File4 implies that File1=File4=File3).   Rows 4 and 5 would be in Group2.

The grouping can be done either at the time of comparing the file or after the result dataframe is created.

I am using Pandas and Python.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using the concept of a graph and its connected components. You will need module `networkx`. First, build a graph from the dataframe. The file names are going to be graph nodes, and two nodes are connected with an edge if the names refer to the identical files:

```
import networkx as nx
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'col1', 'col2')
```

Now, extract the connected components (subgraphs where you can get from any node to any other node):

```
parts = list(nx.connected_components(graph))
# [{1, 2, 3, 4, 8}, {5, 6, 7}]
```

As you can see, the names 1,2,3,4, and 8 refer to the identical files, ad so do the names 5,6, and 7.

Now, you may want to convert the list of parts back to pandas. Enumerate the parts with `enumerate`, convert them into a list of (filename,part_id) pairs, and create a series out of the list:

```
from itertools import chain
parts_series = pd.Series(dict(chain.from_iterable(\
                      [[(name,part_id) for name in filenames] 
                        for part_id,filenames in enumerate(parts)])))
#File1    0
#File2    0
#File3    0
#File4    0
#File5    1
#File6    1
#File7    1
#File8    0
```

Comment: The groups are not just connected components, but equivalence classes. That is, each member of a component has an edge to every other member of that component. Building an entire graph is overkill; if there are n edges and k components, your algorithm is O(n^2) when the task can be done in O(nk).

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes, they are equivalence classes. Yes, there are more efficient ways to solve the problem. I do not claim that my solution is optimal. Yet, I claim that it is correct.

Comment: Fantastic answer!  I never even dreamed of using networkx for this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Write a function `hash_of_file()` that returns a hash of a file given its name. Then do

```
file_to_hash_dict = {file_name: hash_of_file(file_name) for file_name in file_names}
hash_list = list(set(file_to_hash_dict.values()))
group_dict = {file_name:hash_list.index(file_to_hash_dict[file_name]) for file_name in file_names}
```